# Keeping Code DRY without Sacrificing Efficiency

Tags: c++, dry

Suppose for example that I have two functions that are almost exactly the same, that represent a bottleneck of the system, that look something like this, (much more complicated) :

```
void f1( int s )
{
    for( size_t i = 0, END = m_v.size(); i < END; ++i )
    {
        int bin_id = binId( m_v[ i ], s );
        m_result[ bin_id ] += m_w[ i ]; //
    }
}

void f2( int s )
{
    for( size_t i = 0, END = m_v.size(); i < END; ++i )
    {
        int bin_id = binId( m_v[ i ], s );
        m_result[ bin_id ] += 1.f; //
    }
}
```

Everything is the same except that you either use a variable or a constant in one line of the code. As mentioned, suppose the actual code is much more complex. It would be nice not to duplicate it twice with the minor difference, as it requires one to make sure to maintain each identically. I could do something like this to merge them into one:

```
void f3( bool use_weight, int s )
{
    if( use_weight )
    {
        for( size_t i = 0, END = v.size(); i < END; ++i )
        {
            int bin_id = binId( v[ i ], s );
            result[ bin_id ] += m_w[ i ]; //
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        for( size_t i = 0, END = v.size(); i < END; ++i )
        {
            int bin_id = binId( v[ i ], s );
            result[ bin_id ] += 1.f; //
        }
    }
}
```

But this is still duplicating the code, just within a single function. We could do this, but it would give worse performance:

```
void f3( bool use_weight, int s )
{
    for( size_t i = 0, END = v.size(); i < END; ++i )
    {
        int bin_id = binId( v[ i ], s );
        if( use_weight )
        {
            result[ bin_id ] += m_w[ i ]; //
        }
        else 
        {
            result[ bin_id += 1.f; //
        }
    }
}
```

And the calling code looks like this:

```
bool use_weight = something.use_weight();
const int N = very_large_number;
for( int s = 0; s < N; ++s )
{
    f3( use_weight, s );
}
```

Again, assuming the code is much more complicated so that f3, for example is actually duplicating alot of logic.

Comment: Factoring out the code into an `inline` function that takes a parameter, and passing in either a variable or a constant should avoid code duplication, and have the compiler emit the appropriate code, each time.

Comment: Would there be any difference you passed the `bool` as a template parameter?

Comment: You could use lambdas for the code that differs in the two variants, and set a variable to the appropriate callback before the loop. But the function call overhead is likely to be onerous if this is a bottleneck function.

Comment: Not an answer, but... Your `f3()` will probably run a lot faster than you think. Modern CPUs are pretty good at branch prediction; code like this (branching on a local variable loop invariant value) will probably cost you 1 cycle on each iteration. Maybe even less thanks to superscalar magic. Which is a long way of saying the usual rule: If you care about performance, never estimate; always profile.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, sometimes optimizing code reusability can often go out the door, but in your example it would likely be better to utilize Polymorphism.  Classes and function should take in arguments that they are working on and not work member variables.  Making an 'uber' function or class that 'does it all' is usually a mistake.  These sort of classes and functions just get more and more bloated as time goes on.

So, the code would ideally use an Interface, and the needed parser would be injected. :)

```
var parser1 = new HotSauceParser();
parser.parse(arrayData);

var parser2 = new WeightParser();
parser2.setWeights(m_w); // in many langages you can chain this.
parser.parse(arrayData);
```

This follows the [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and it easily testable.  Then you could write a class that decides when to use one class or the other.  The logic of HOW to parse is encapsulated in the Parsers themselves.

As far as efficiency goes, typically if you are parsing an Array the performance concerns are about how BIG that array is and do you have to walk the entire structure.

Just be careful with 'DRY'ing your code, it easy to over-DRY your code and fall into common pitfalls like over use of Inheritance and/or creating Classes and Functions with 'Feature Envy'.

You might want to check out the *Clean Code* book and *S.O.L.I.D.*.